# Unable to modify custom error message for Error code 405

Tags: python, flask, error-handling, http-error, error-code

My goal is to change the default 405 error code from "The method is not allowed for the requested URL" to "Not allowed method". However my code below doesn't work (this code was also used to other error code and they seem to work fine)

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.errorhandler(405)
def method_not_allowed(error):
    return make_response(jsonify(Error = 'Not allowed method'), 405)
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Can you add an example of your code that should trigger a 405 error ?

Comment: The code above is supposed to be triggered generally by all endpoints (I placed the code in app.py). So if some error occurred in an endpoint, it should return the 405 custom error message.

Comment: Just to be clear, this code will be triggered only for HTTP 405 errors, not for any error. For example if you send a POST request to a page that only accepts GET requests, you would have this error. If you had a 404 handler, then it would catch requests to non-existing pages etc.